# Table inside Django model for Order in E-Commerce site

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, many-to-many, one-to-many

I am developing a Grocery Store Website using Django for the backend.

I have a model named "Order" which contains fields Customer name, date, address, mobile no, payment method, status, etc, and one most important field Order List (This should be in table format(one to many) and contains multiple fields product name, price, quantity). I have a products table and this product name, price will be from that products table. In short actually I want models inside a model.

If I create a record in the order I want to add multiple products(with product name, price, and quantity) in the same record.

I want such a structure in Django-Admin for Order Table

```
Customer Name:              Mobile No.
Date:                       Address:

Order list :
| Product Name| Price | Quantity |
|:----------- |:-----:| --------:|
| Product 1   | 10.20 |     2    |
| Product 2   | 15.20 |     5    |
| Product 3   | 17.20 |     7    |

Payment Method:                       Payment Status:
Order Status:
```

Model for the above table will be something like this

```
customer_name = foreignkey(User)
mobile_no = charfield(max_length =12)
date = datefield
address = charfield
order_list = One2Many Field / this should contain another model/table (having fields product_name, quantity, and price)
payment_method = charfield
.
.
```

Please help me to get the possible solution to this problem.

Here are the models I am using.

But using this will create a new order for every single product in the checkout list.
But I want a single order record for all the products in the checkout list.

```
# For Product details
class ProductDetails(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price= models.FloatField()
    mrp= models.FloatField()
    main_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_img')
    img1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_img')
    img2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_img')
    img3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_img')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='produits', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, related_name='produits', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_details = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    trending = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


# For Order Table
class Order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    cutomer_name = models.ForeignKey(User,  related_name='cust_name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length= 500)
    mobile_no = models.CharField(max_length = 12)
    product = models.ForeignKey(ProductDetails,  related_name='product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    price = models.FloatField(default=1)
    total_cost = models.FloatField(default=1)
    order_state_list = [
        ('pending', 'Pending'),
        ('cancelled', 'Cancelled'),
        ('confirm', 'Confirm'),
        ('on_the_way', 'On the way'),    
        ('delivered', 'Delivered'),    
        ]
    order_status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=order_state_list, default="pending")

    payment_state_list = [
        ('pending', 'Pending'),
        ('cancelled', 'Cancelled'),
        ('confirm', 'Confirm') 
        ]
    payment_status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=payment_state_list, default="pending")
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I want something similar to this. (I was using Odoo(ERP Dev framework of python) I had created this in Odoo using the One2Many field)
[image]

Comment: Can you share the model as well?

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
class Product(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
   
class Order(models.Model):
   order_code = models.CharField()


class Purchase(models.Model):
   product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
   quantity = models.IntegerField()
   order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
```

therefore when you create a purchase you can attach it to an order
and to retrive all purchases related to an order you can

```
purchase_list = Purchase.objects.filter(order=[some_pk])
```

in order to add products to the order, just :

```
my_order = Order.objects.create()
products_list = [p1,p2 ] #etc
for product in product_list:
   product.order = my_order
   product.save()
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I will edit the question again.

Comment: Thank You, I have changed the question. I hope it's a bit clear now.

Comment: I edited my answer as well, I check the code snippets, it should do the job

Comment: In your code, you have created a model for purchase. which is linked to the Product on creating a purchase record will get a product from the Product model but I want to add multiple Products in a single purchase record

Comment: it is just a matter of semantics, you can call the model whatever you want, here I am adding the purchases in Order model, you can call the Order model purchase if you want, but the idea stays the same. 
We are not adding products to order, but each product sold is a purchase, the we link multiple purchases to an order. so here the order is linked to multiple purchases. In other words, multiple purchases to A SINGLE ORDER RECORD. Just swap the names if you prefer

Comment: I think I made the question very confusing. I tried to make it more clear now. please read the question again and help me with the solution. Thank you